# Scala jdbc mysql json field encoding issue

Tags: mysql, scala, jdbc, slick

I have a MySQL table with fields of json type. The table and the db have utf8 charset.

The problem I having is that when I query data, the value of these fields are strings in incorrect charset and unicode characters are messed up: like, instead of `é` I get `Ã©`.

There's no problems with other text fields.

I tried using Quill and Slick. The connection config is like this:

```
characterEncoding="UTF-8"
useUnicode=true
```

I also tried `jdbc:mysql://"${DB_HOST}/${DB_NAME}&useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8`

The only workaround I found is to manually convert strings to another charset like

```
new String(string.getBytes("Windows-1252"), "UTF-8")
```

Is there a better way?